# Is it possible to refactor this function?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C but I am finding it hard to keep the code neat and tidy.

For example, I have this piece of code, that in some branches does the exact same thing as the others. So, I am wondering, can I merge those branches together to get a cleaner code? Is this good as is? (consider that this code runs in a for loop)

```
if(rx_color <= 60)
{
    set_sensor_mode(sn_rx_color, "COL-COLOR");
    get_sensor_value(0, sn_rx_color, &rx_color);
    printf("rx_color is %d\n", rx_color);
    if ( rx_color == 3)
    {
        printf("turn right\n");
        killMotors(0);
        return;
    } else 
    {
        pidLine(speed);
    }
}
else if (lx_color <= 60)
{

    set_sensor_mode(sn_lx_color, "COL-COLOR");
    get_sensor_value(0, sn_lx_color, &lx_color);
    printf("lx_color is %d\n", lx_color);
    if(lx_color == 3)
    {
        printf("turn left\n");
        killMotors(0);
        return;
    } else 
    {
        pidLine(speed);
    }
}
else
{
    pidLine(speed); 
}
```

As you can see multiple times I call `pidLine(speed)`. This just feels wrong, but I can't come up with a way to clean it.

Is it even possible?

Comment: you'll create a new function that takes these for its parameters (sn_rx_color OR sn_lx_color, rx_color OR lx_color).  I didn't know the types for the "color" variables.  Remove all the "else" statements and just leave `pidLine(speed);` as the final statement in your code. Your return statements will prevent it from being called unless necessary

Comment: You can set some local variables according to the two conditions, and merge the duplicated code using those variables.

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger So basically are you suggesting to move this piece of junk outside this function?

Comment: @A.Dandelion I suppose you could say that.  Check this code out.  It's not perfect, I typed it up very quickly but it should give you an idea:  https://pastebin.com/FZkgC6m9

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger 
I see. That makes sense. Could you make an answer so that I can select it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that *consistent* between your two chunks of code is just copy-pasted to your new function.  Anything that is *variable* between the two chunks of code become your variables, or parameters that you pass to the new function.

```
int somefunction(int a, int b, const char* direction)
{
    if(b <= 60) {
        set_sensor_mode(a, "COL-COLOR");
        get_sensor_value(0, a, &b);
        printf("b is %d\n", b);
        return 1;
    }
    if (b == 3) {
        printf("%s %s%c","turn",direction,'\n');
        killMotors(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And you can call them like this:

```
somefunction(sn_rx_color,rx_color,"right") || somefunction(sn_lx_color,lx_color,"left") || pidLine(speed);
```

Comment: This contains “turn right”, but the original code has “turn left” and “turn right” in its branches. This receives `b` as a value, but the original passes addresses to subroutines, so they have access to the pointed-to object and may change it, so this code needs to receive an address, not a value.

Comment: I think I already edited to fix that... how does it look now?

Comment: This code prints “b” in a message, but the original prints “rx_color” or “lx_color”.

Comment: Yeah it's not perfect. I'm not going to worry about that... the OP can figure that one out.

Comment: I see no edit that would fix that. `somefunction` receives `b` as a value. It needs a pointer.

Comment: Actually, aren't `a` and `b` signed integers?  The printf statement seems to indicate that

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger: They could be `int` or any narrower integer type, which would be promoted to `int` for the `printf` call.

Answer (score 3):

```
static int Stuff(Color sn_color, Color *color, char *name, char *direction)
{
    set_sensor_mode(sn_color, "COL-COLOR");
    get_sensor_value(0, sn_color, color);
    printf("%s_color is %d\n", name, *color);
    if (*color == 3)
    {
        printf("turn %s\n", direction);
        killMotors(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

…
    int DoPidLine;

    if (rx_color <= 60)
        DoPidLine = Stuff(sn_rx_color, &rx_color, "rx", "right")
    else if (lx_color <= 60)
        DoPidLine = Stuff(sn_lx_color, &lx_color, "lx", "left")
    else
        DoPidLine = 1;
    if (DoPidLine)
        pidLine(speed);
```

The latter part, from the “…” down, could be a single statement:

```
if (rx_color <= 60 ? Stuff(sn_rx_color, &rx_color, "rx", "right") :
    lx_color <= 60 ? Stuff(sn_lx_color, &lx_color, "lx", "left" ) :
    1)
    pidLine(speed)
```

Another alternative is:

```
static void Stuff(Speed speed, Color sn_color, Color *color, char *name, char *direction)
{
    if (name)
    {
        set_sensor_mode(sn_color, "COL-COLOR");
        get_sensor_value(0, sn_color, &color);
        printf("%s_color is %d\n", name, color);
        if (color == 3)
        {
            printf("turn %s\n", direction);
            killMotors(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    pidLine(speed);
}

…
    if (rx_color <= 60)
        Stuff(speed, sn_rx_color, &rx_color, "rx", "right")
    else if (lx_color <= 60)
        Stuff(speed, sn_lx_color, &lx_color, "lx", "left")
    else
        Stuff(speed, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this 'cleans up' the code. Maybe inserted in the context it looks nicer than this. Anyhow, this is how I solved it https://pastebin.com/gVLFLw79. I'm quite proud as I think it looks very nice. Thanks anyways! (I missed a return statement, can't edit the paste)